# posting to wall from iOS device (via link not active)

Tags: facebook

I have been able to post to a users wall for some time and it is signed by the app at the bottom of the posting with "xxx hours ago via (name of app)".

This via (name of app) use to be a link that would take you to my facebook app page.  The link is no longer active.  It is just text.  Anyone have any ideas as to how to get it back to being a link?